# Loop with a line of code that keeps increasing

Tags: vbscript

I have VBS code I exported from a macro recording application.

I want to use a Do While loop statement to repeat the code. There is a line in the code that keeps increasing by an additional one in each loop and I have no idea how to go around it.

Here is the VBS code

```
bzhao.SendKey "x"
bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

'Next loop

bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "x"
bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

' Next loop

bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "x"
bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

' Next Loop

bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
bzhao.SendKey "x"
bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

'And so on
```

I want to write a loop statement that can increase the number of this line of code in each loop. `bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"`

Answer (score 0):

This would be a loop within a loop. I think this should work:

```
Sub looper()

    Const numberofLoops As Long = 20 ' or whatever "and so on" is

    Dim i As Long, z As Long

    'Next loop
    For i = 1 To numberofLoops
        z = 1

        Do While z < i
            bzhao.SendKey "<Down>"
            z = z + 1
        Loop

        bzhao.SendKey "x"
        bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"
        bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll test the code and update you soon. Thanks PGSystemTester.